НЕ срабатывает адаптив html + css
Не подскажете почему на телефоне не срабатывает адаптив при разрешении 539px, а именно сожержимое страницы не "сжимается" до размеров экрана и приходится скролить? Спасибо.


@media screen and (max-width: 540px) {
.robo {
    padding-top: 16%;
}

.main-title {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 18%;
}

. main-text {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 35%;
}
}
<section class="main-content">
    <div class="create-main">
        <div class="create">
             <img src="images/robo.png" alt="robo" class="robo">
                <div class="main-info">
                    <h1 class="main-title">Create your own exchange in two clicks</h1>
                    <p class="main-text">Convenient and secure crypto solutions for your business all in one place.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
</section>




наскок помню @media screen - экран монитора(компьютерного, не телефонного)

Скорее всего опять забытый meta viewport

viewport не забыт)))   

Ну ещё можно отметить что . main-text это не .main-text

Исправил, но всё же содержимое страниц так и не адаптируется под выставленное разрешение. всё так же бегаю слева на право при разрешении 412 Х 915. Дело в том, что контейнеры ведут себя правильно на странице, но объекты всё так же выходят за пределы экрана.

Ну тогда остаётся просить [mcve], потому что на показанном сейчас в вопросе куске кода такого поведения не наблюдается (да и не может наблюдаться, тут выходить за пределы экрана банально нечему)

Понял. Прочту условие составления минимального куска кода и опишусь. Благодарю за внимание к моему вопросу.

Всё же выяснил причину. Дело было в  фиксированном положении картинки. И всё же спасибо за внимание к вопросу. Где Вам поставить плюсик?)))
